# Changing the picture description in the preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im curently creating a picture gallery for my project in school. I came across the problem that i don't know how to add a picture description that will only show under the big preview picture and not next to the small pictures at the top. Every small picture will have a different description. I tried some stuff myself but i failed miserably, Im still new to all of this :)

Any solutions to that problem?

```
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link href="galery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body background="cosmic.jpg">
  <div class="gallery" align="center">



    <div class="smallpics">
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture1" src="images/picture1.png"  /> 
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture2" src="images/picture2.png"  /> 
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture3" src="images/picture3.png"  /> 
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture4" src="images/picture4.png"  />
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture5" src="images/picture5.png"  />
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture6" src="images/picture6.png"  />
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture7" src="images/picture7.png"  />
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture8" src="images/picture8.png"  />
<img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src" id="picture9" src="images/picture9.png"  />
</div>

     <div class="bigpic" align="center">
   <img id="bigpic" src="images/picture1.png" alt="" />

</div>
```

Comment: You should consider centralised event handling from an external JS file. This has a number of benefits, not the least of which is it'll cut out a tonne of that repetitive `onclick` code from your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="smallpics">
   <img onclick="getElementById('bigpic').src=this.src; getElementById('bigpicDesc').innerHTML(this.alt) " id="picture1" src="images/picture1.png" alt="The Description" /> 
....
</div>

<div class="bigpic" align="center">
   <img id="bigpic" src="images/picture1.png" alt="" />
   <div id="bigpicDesc"> </div>

</div>
```

or

```
<div class="smallpics">
       <img onclick="showInBig(this)" id="picture1" src="images/picture1.png" alt="The Description" /> 
....
</div>

<div class="bigpic" align="center">
   <img id="bigpic" src="images/picture1.png" alt="" />
   <div id="bigpicDesc"> </div>

</div>
function showInBig(element){

 document.getElementById('bigpic').setAttribute('src',element.getAttribute('src')); 

 document.getElementById('bigpicDesc').innerHTML(element.element.getAttribute('alt'));
}
```

Given that alt of the small images are the descriptions.

Comment: Using the `alt` attribute with the image for this is much better than a custom `data-*` attribute, because you have to provide it and with related text. +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to clean up your HTML and separate out the JavaScript. This has a number of benefits. It keeps your HTML and JS separate without muddying one with the other.

All of your `onclick` code can be handled thus:

```
var big_pic = document.querySelector('#bigpic');
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (!/^picture\d+$/.test(evt.target.id)) return;
    big_pic.src = evt.target.src;
}, false);
```

Now, let's consider adding a description. The first question is, how are you going to store these, and in relation to the images?

An obvious solution is to store them in a data attribute on the pictures elements. So just as we read the `src` from the clicked pic's element, we'll read its description from the same source.

So our elements become:

```
<img id='picture1' src='some/src.jpg' data-descr='Picture description here' />
```

Then you're going to need a description placeholder in the big picture area, so add a paragraph.

Finally, change the above JS code to factor in the description also:

```
var
big_pic = document.querySelector('#bigpic'),
big_pic_descr = document.querySelector('.bigpic p');
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (!/^picture\d+$/.test(evt.target.id)) return;
    big_pic.src = evt.target.src;
    big_pic_descr.innerHTML = evt.target.getAttribute('data-descr');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be done in 2 ways, first by making use of `data-` attribute <sup>**(1)**</sup>

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/9egeLnx1/2/)

```js
var pics = document.querySelectorAll('.smallpics img'),
  bigPic = document.getElementById('bigpic'),
  descP = document.getElementById('description');

for (var i = 0, ln = pics.length; i < ln; i++) {
  // we pass each img with its src and data-desc attributes to the function.
  var $this = pics[i];
  theClickFunction($this, $this.getAttribute('src'), $this.getAttribute('data-desc'));
}

function theClickFunction($th, $src, $desc) {
  $th.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //on click we update the bigpic display and thedescription  paragraph
    bigPic.setAttribute('src', $src);
    bigPic.style.display = 'block';
    descP.innerHTML = $desc;
  });
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.smallpics img { width: 19%; cursor: pointer; }
#bigpic { display:none}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" align="center">
  <div class="smallpics">
    <img id="pic1" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic1" data-desc="description of picture 1" />
    <img id="pic2" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic2" data-desc="description of picture 2" />
    <img id="pic3" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic3" data-desc="description of picture 3" />
    <img id="pic4" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic4" data-desc="description of picture 4" />
    <img id="pic5" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic5" data-desc="description of picture 5" />
    <img id="pic6" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic6" data-desc="description of picture 6" />
    <img id="pic7" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic7" data-desc="description of picture 7" />
    <img id="pic8" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic8" data-desc="description of picture 8" />
    <img id="pic9" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic9" data-desc="description of picture 9" />
    <img id="pic10" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100?text=pic10" data-desc="description of picture 10" />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="bigpic" align="center">
    <img id="bigpic" src="images/picture1.png" alt="" />
    <p id="description"></p>
  </div>
```

---

The other way is by using some hidden element, I used `<ul>` with its `li`s here but it could be `div`s or `p` etc.., while this way adds extra markup to the page it suits better when you have HTML, styled and/or long descriptions rather than just normal text.

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/9egeLnx1/3/)

```js
var pics = document.querySelectorAll('.smallpics img'),
  DescLis = document.querySelectorAll('#hiddenDescs li'),
  bigPic = document.getElementById('bigpic'),
  descP = document.getElementById('description');

for (var i = 0, ln = pics.length; i < ln; i++) {
  // we pass each img with its src attribute.
  var $this = pics[i];
  theClickFunction($this, $this.getAttribute('src'), i);
}

function theClickFunction($th, $src, i) {
  $th.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //on click we update the bigpic display and thedescription  paragraph
    bigPic.setAttribute('src', $src);
    bigPic.style.display = 'block';
    // get the inner html of the corresponding li and inject it as innerHTML
    // of the descreption p
    descP.innerHTML = DescLis[i].innerHTML;
  });
}
```

---

<sup>**(1)**</sup> <sub>Using **`alt`** attribute, as in [@Thuin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045531/2081719), rather than **`data-*`** is better because: *`This attribute defines the alternative text describing the image. Users will see this text displayed if the image URL is wrong, the image is not in one of the supported formats, or if the image is not yet downloaded.`*</sub>